# Unable to update the EntitySet X because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC and EF 6, DB first model. I have the following three tables in my DB:

Policy

```
...
PolicyID INT
...
```

PolicySet
    ...
    PolicySetID INT
    ...

and a policysetpolicies which is a mapping table with just two fields:
PolicySetPolicies

```
PolicyID
PolicySetID
```

I am building up a wizard-like interface, and at the final step I want to persist the changes in the database, between a policyset and its containing policies. Here is the last bit of my code:

```
foreach (Policy importance in policies)
            {
                Policy policy = db.Policies.Find(importance.PolicyID);
                policy.Importance = importance.Importance;
                PolicySetHelper.PolicySetSession.PolicySet.Policies.Add(policy);
            }


        PolicySetHelper.PolicySetSession.PolicySet.Resources.Add(resource);
        db.PolicySets.Add(PolicySetHelper.PolicySetSession.PolicySet);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Additional information: Unable to update the EntitySet 'PolicyPolicySets' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

I have read up a bit, and it seems that for some reason EF is perceiving the Mapping table as a view? I am not sure how to work around this...

Comment: We need to see the mapping to tell more about this.

Comment: Does your entity has Primary Key ?

Comment: Composite keys on the table did the trick. Thanks mo. I just don't get why it is not explained more clearly somewhere..